# How to transfer transmission configuration to another machine?

Tags: configuration, transmission, bittorrent

I'd like to know how can I keep my old Transmission data when I do a new system installation.

Is there any way to keep my statistics, rate upload/download, etc., and use them in my new installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the folder located at `/home/your-user-name/.config/transmission/` and place it at the same path location on your new installation.

Simplest way would be to have an Ubuntu One account and mark that folder as a Cloud Folder, syncing the configuration across installations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jacob.  I tried to find the folder ".transmission" in my home, but I didn't look for it into ".config".